# System.out.print("Enter the speed limit (>0,<=80): ");

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicketDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner iq = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ticket Manager");
        System.out.println("");
        Ticket t = new Ticket("",0,0);
        System.out.print("Enter the name of the violator: ");
        t.setName(iq.next());
        //System.out.print("Enter the speed of the violator (>0): ");
        //t.setSpeed(iq.nextInt());
        do{
            System.out.print("Enter the speed of the violator (>0): ");
            t.setSpeed(iq.nextInt());
        }while(t.getSpeed()< 0);
        System.out.print("Enter the speed limit (>0,<=80): ");
        t.setSpeedLimit(iq.nextInt());
        if(t.getSpeedLimit()>0 || t.getSpeedLimit() <=80) {
            System.out.print("Enter the speed limit (>0,<=80): ");
            t.setSpeedLimit(iq.nextInt());
        }
        System.out.print("Was this in a school zone(Y/N): ");
        t.setSchoolZone((iq.next()).matches("Y"));
        System.out.print("Was this in a work zone (Y/N):");
        t.setWorkZone((iq.next()).matches("Y"));
        System.out.println(t.printNotice());
    }
}
```

`if(t.getSpeedLimit()>0 || t.getSpeedLimit() >=80)`

The loop of speed limit is not working

Comment: `if(t.getSpeedLimit()>0 || t.getSpeedLimit() <=80) {` can never be true

Comment: What's the question here? What have you done so far?

Comment: When I compile, the second loop is not working

Comment: it needs to be greater than cero and less or equal of 80

Comment: It can certainly be true, for any positive integer, but it doesn't test what the OP wants. @ScaryWombat

Comment: @user207421 Sorry I meant it couldn't be false

Answer (score 0):

```
do{
        System.out.print("Enter the speed limit (>0,<=80): ");
        t.setSpeedLimit(iq.nextInt());
    }while(t.getSpeedLimit()<=0 || t.getSpeedLimit() >80);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low quality answers. Add some explanation. Why does this code work?

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.